# How to give matrix representation of linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How can i form of the matrix representation in the following exercise?

> Given the linear maps $f$ and $g$
>
> $$f\left(\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1\\ \lambda_2\\ \lambda_3\end{bmatrix}\right)=\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_3-\lambda_1\\\lambda_2-\lambda_1\end{bmatrix}\\ g\left(\begin{bmatrix}\mu_1\\\mu_2\end{bmatrix}\right)=\begin{bmatrix}\mu_2-\mu_1\\ -2\mu_1\\ \mu_1+\mu_2\end{bmatrix}$$
>
> find the matrix repesentation of $g\circ f$.

Comment: Consider the first case, $f$. With what matrix do you need to multiply
$$
\left[ \lambda_1, \quad \lambda_2, \quad \lambda_3 \right]^T
$$
To obtain the matrix on the right side? Hint: It contains only $0$'s and $\pm 1$.

Answer (score 2):

The matrix representation of $T:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m$ (in the canonical basis) is simply the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}T(e_1)& T(e_2)&\cdots &T(e_n)\end{pmatrix}.$$

This can be easily computed in this instance.

Comment: Can you please suggest to me what does the cicle between the functions mean?

Comment: I will not do that.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is represented (in the standard bases) by $$M_f= \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 & 1\\ -1 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

and $g$ by

$$M_g= \begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1\\
-2 & 0\\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now compute $M_g M_f$ as matrices